# Searching Git's commit history with 2 lines padding to the search string?

Tags: git

I'm searching git commit's history for this string: `********RMR` via this command :

`git log -p -S****RMR` ( asterisks are replacements).

It does work but I see many irrelevant lines to the search string :

[image]

I mean look how many irrelevant lines are displayed where all I was searching was the first red arrow.

**Question:**

Is there any option to get only the search string with `n` lines before it along with `n` lines after it ?

I mean - getting only this:

```
line 1
line 2
*****BRMR
line 4
line 5
```

*nb ( I know that the other lines are the actual commits..., still I want the searched text only ( with padded rows).*

Answer (score -1):

Try with *git grep*

```
git grep <regexp>
```

Search working tree for lines of text matching regular expression regexp1 or regexp2:

```
git grep -e <regexp1> [--or] -e <regexp2>
```